# Access span.html() with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the content of the second span (result should be 2021) with jquery.

```
<div class="prepPeriodItemSelection">
  <select id="ddlPrepPeriodItem_3" data-loaded-period-type="6" data-loaded-date-var="1" style="display:none;">
    <option value="y_2021" strstartdate="2021/01/01" strstopdate="2021/12/31">2021</option>
    <option value="y_2020" strstartdate="2020/01/01" strstopdate="2020/12/31">2020</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" class="ui-multiselect ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all Theme-multiselect" title="" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" style="width: 225px;">
   <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s"></span>
   <span>2021</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

There is another div with class .prepPeriodItemSelection in the code so I tried this ( and dozens of variations...)

`alert($('.prepPeriodItemSelection:nth-child(2) button span:nth-child(2)').html());`

it always returns null

any ideas whats wrong

Comment: `:nth-child(2)` will select *all* the divs with that class that are nth-child.  You (probably) want `$(".prepPeriodItemSelection:nth-child").eq(1).find("button span:nth-child(2)").html())` if this is the *second* instance of that class.   Note `:nth-child` is 1-based so `(2)` is the second while `.eq` is 0-based so `(1)` is the second.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working, I tried also to output only `alert($(".prepPeriodItemSelection:nth-child(2)").html());`
but it also returns null. i suspect it has to do with this specific asp.net application where the element is not available in the DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this acceptable?

```
$('.prepPeriodItemSelection:nth-child(2) button > span:nth-child(2)').html();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working, I tried also to output only `alert($(".prepPeriodItemSelection:nth-child(2)").html());`
but it also returns null. i suspect it has to do with this specific asp.net application where the element is not available in the DOM

Answer (score -1):

My bad, I had a error in the wait loop so the code was execute before the element was available in the DOM , I found another solution that work s now. Thanks to all , your support and input is very much appreciated.